# Fibonacci Sequence in Python using a matrix class, overload the mult operator and write a function

Tags: python, fibonacci

I need to write a Python function that computes Fib(n) using this technique:

1. Write a matrix class, overload the mult operator.
2. Write Fib(n) function.

---

```
class matrix:
    """ A class that stores an m x n matrix and overload the multiplication
    operator to perform matrix multiplication. """
    def __init__(self,data):
        """Class Instance Data
        What do we need to store?
        assume self has m rows and n columns, so
        data is a list of lists with len(data) = m
        and len(data[i]) = n for every i. """
        self.data = data
        # Assume data is a properly formatted list of lists

    # Class methods
    # overload the multiplication operator        
    def __mul__(self,B):
        """ Define function to calculate self*B
        For every i,j spot in self*B
        self*B [i][j] = sum(self[i][k] * B[k][j]) for k = 0 to n-1
        Assume self has m rows and n columns
        and B has n rows and t columns
        (and raise an exception if this isn't true)"""

        n = len(self.data)
        m = 
        t =  
        Ans = []
        for row in range(m):
            Ans.append([]) # row i
            for col in range(t):
                # here's the pseudocode from the board, translated to python
                Ans[row].append(0)
                for k in range(n):
                    Ans[row][col]+=self[row][k] * B[k][col]
```

Comment: Would you like some code?

Comment: Did you try anything already? Post your code attempt within your question.

Comment: This is not a code delivery site. First you post what you have done.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].